# Multiple CRM (Sales Cloud/Service Cloud) to Marketing Cloud BUs

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

With multi-org I know it's possible to connect:

1. Multiple business units connected to multiple orgs.
2. Multiple business units connected to a single org.

If I have 5 Sales Cloud orgs, would the following scenarios be possible?:

1. Connect each of the 5 orgs to its own BU.
2. Connect all 5 Sales Cloud orgs to one Parent.

Also, would Service/Community Cloud also be able to be enabled for these in the same manner?

There isn't a lot of resources out there for using multiple orgs in this way so trying to shed some light for myself and the community if anyone has any helpful knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

- N MC Business Units => Single SFDC Org (Possible)
- N SFDC Orgs => Single MC Business Unit (Not possible)

If linked multiple BU's to a single SFDC Org and same MC API user is used in all of those => All synchronized data sources will be available in all of those BUs

You want to sync different objects? => Use different API users.

You will still benefit from Parent/Child architecture in terms of BU and will be able to access relevant data by leveraging SQL activities (Child BU) and adding ENT. prefix when selecting from a Data Extension that is shared or available only in the Parent BU : "FROM ENT.Contact_Salesforce"

In terms of Community Cloud - we are talking about integrations/Journey Builder